# Add Icon To Title Property of Material Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am new to using material-table. I am simply trying to add an icon to the end of the title on the material-table title property, but it is not as simple as I thought. Is it even possible? My code snippet is below...

```
<MaterialTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    title={`Summary View ${(
      <BsInfoSquare onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} />
    )}`}
```

Comment: if the title can be a component, it should look like this, `title={<div>Hello World</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

The type definitions at https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/types/index.d.ts show that `title` is a `string` or a `ReactElement`, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
<MaterialTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    title={<>
      Summary view
      <MyIcon />
    </>}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the link provided as well.